# Volume preserving linear map

Tags: multivariable-calculus, linear-transformations, lebesgue-integral, determinant, volume

I know a result that volume preserving linear maps have determinant 1. How do I prove it? I understand it has to do with change of variables but does “derivative of a linear map” make sense? (Considering derivative is itself a linear map)

Comment: If you have a linear map, then the jacobian is simply the (absolute value of the) determinant, and so is a constant, which factors out of your integral. So you are multiplying volume by your determinant.

Answer (score 1):

Derivative of a linear map does not always make sense but the Jacobian does and it is what appears in the variable change formula.

Comment: derivative (in the sense of Frechet) of a linear map does make perfect sense: if $V,W$ are real/complex finite-dimensional spaces, and $T:V\to W$ is linear then for any $a\in V$, $DT_a(\cdot)=T(\cdot)$ "a linear transformation is its own linear approximation". The Jacobian matrix is simply the matrix representation of this linear map with respect to chosen bases on the domain and target space (and when we're dealing with $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $\Bbb{R}^m$ we simply use the "standard" bases). The Jacobian determinant is then of course nothing but the determinant of this matrix when $V=W=\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo: what are you trying to say?

Comment: that the first part of your sentence isn't right

Comment: @peek-a-boo: You can of course view the Jacobian as the "derivative" but I do not think the OP meant that. Again, I am not going to argue with you about what the OP thought.  The point of the answer is the second part of it which is that the Jacobian appears in the change of variables formula. This is always true for any smooth map between vector spaces, not just a linear map.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the determinant of a set of vectors is motivated to be the signed volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the vectors. So in your case the determinant of a linear map is given by the volume of the image of the unit cube under that map with some sign. From this follows trivial that if your map preserves volumes then this determinant must be $\pm1$.

In the other direction: If a linear map has determinant $\pm1$ you get that it at least preserves the volumes of cuboids. From this it is not hard to see that it preserves the volumes of all sets (by using approximation by cuboids).